# MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a complex query and it was working fine before adding one more line:
the working query:

```
         $query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
                    FROM realestate
                    INNER JOIN users ON id_user = users.id
                    LEFT JOIN pic ON id_realestate = realestate.id
                    group by realestate.id
                    ORDER BY {$order}
                    LIMIT 0 , 10";
```

the value of `$order` is `date DESC`

after adding one more line, here is the query:

```
         $query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
                    FROM realestate
                    {$place} 
                    INNER JOIN users ON id_user = users.id
                    LEFT JOIN pic ON id_realestate = realestate.id
                    group by realestate.id
                    ORDER BY {$order}
                    LIMIT 0 , 10";
```

`$place` has this value `WHERE address =1` the field name `address` doesn't duplicate in other tables.
I get this `mysql` error :

```
  Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near
 'INNER JOIN users ON id_user = users.id LEFT JOIN pic ON id_realestate = real' 
  at line 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` clauses must come **before** `WHERE` clauses. You have your clauses in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Table References comes before the WHERE portion. The following should be the correct order:

```
     $query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
                FROM realestate
                INNER JOIN users ON id_user = users.id
                LEFT JOIN pic ON id_realestate = realestate.id
                {$place} 
                group by realestate.id
                ORDER BY {$order}
                LIMIT 0 , 10";
```

`JOIN` statements are part of the `FROM` table references.